# Setting java.home or xml.java.home in Visual Studio Settings

Tags: java, json, xml, visual-studio-code

## Overview

I am trying to setup a Visual Studio code extension which will help me build an XML file based on a Schema.

This extension has the following requirements:

(**Note**: I have Java JDK 8+ installed)

---

#### Requirements

- Java JDK (or JRE) 8 or more recent  Ensure Java path is set in
  either: `xml.java.home` in VSCode preferences
- `java.home` in VSCode preferences
- Environment variable JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME

**Note**: The path should end at the parent folder that contains the bin folder.
Example Path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0 if bin exists at /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin.
Note: If the path is not set, the extension will attempt to find the path to the JDK or JRE.

---

## Question

After settings the java.home property in my settings.json file, and upon hovering over the data (which is grayed out) it says that `Unknown Configuration Setting`. As a result the extension does not appear to work. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my settings.json

```
{
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[xml]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "fabianlauer.vs-code-xml-format"
    },
    "java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_241\\bin",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true
}
```

#### Extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, 'XML' extension has no configuration property of 'java.home'. You need to install [Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) extension to get this configuration property.

Secondly, "java.home": "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241", without "\bin", as you have descripted in Note.